# Select2 search input not working on bootstrap5

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, bootstrap-5

I cannot click on the search input dropdown. First of all, I already googled and this is a common problem for select2 with bootstrap3 or bootstrap4, however for bootstrap 5 its a little bit different (I tried remove z-index on bootstrap 4 and its working), I already tried solutions like z-index, `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};`, `$('#mySelect2').select2({ dropdownParent: $('#myModal') });`, and several css but still wont work.

Maybe im missing something im not sure, its been like 4 days, hope u guys can help me.

here jsFiddle :
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/run5wchk/30/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Really not sure why, but dropdownParent will fix it.

```
$('.select2').each(function () {
    $(this).select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap-5',
        dropdownParent: $(this).parent(),
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the select was shown on a dialog modal form.

When I removed `modal=true` then it worked

Answer (score -1):

Just simply remove (`tabindex="-1"`) attribute.

I got the same issue recently, after removing the tab index attribute, it's working nicely.

Comment: This doesn't work. I removed the tabindex="-1" and no change.

Comment: Is it working properly outside of the modal?